# Assignment in function declaration

Tags: php

The following function seems to take `user_id` as an argument. However, it also seems to assign the value `false` to that variable. What's really happening there? There doesn't seems to be much point of using any argument if its value is set in the function anyway. Plus, the phpdoc indicates that `user_id` is an int, while the assigment implies it's a boolean.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

```
/**
 * Determine if user is a site admin.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param int $user_id (Optional) The ID of a user. Defaults to the current user.
 * @return bool True if the user is a site admin.
 */
function is_super_admin( $user_id = false ) {
// ...
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check the example 3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

```
<?php
function makecoffee($type = "cappuccino")
{
    return "Making a cup of $type.\n";
}
echo makecoffee();
echo makecoffee(null);
echo makecoffee("espresso");
?>
```

The above example will output:

Making a cup of cappuccino.
Making a cup of.
Making a cup of espresso.

Comment: Ah I see, it's a default value.

Comment: Please make a big one :)

Answer (score 2):

*false* is the default value of the parameter. If you call `is_super_admin()`,  $user_id has the value *false* inside the method body.